# When compactly supported cohomology ring is zero?

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, poincare-duality

The compactly supported cohomology (over rational) of a compact manifold is the same as ordinary cohomology. Also, we can relate the compactly supported cohomology of the oriented non-compact manifold with ordinary cohomology using Poincare duality. 
How we can understand the compactly supported cohomology of the open non-oriented manifold. For example, compactly supported cohomology of open Mobius band is zero. My first question is that when compactly supported cohomology is zero? My Second question is that if a manifold is open non-oriented and M is rationally acyclic then it compactly supported cohomology is zero or not? In case of compact or open oriented manifold, the compactly supported is not zero due to Poincare duality.

Comment: You identify the compactly supported cohomology to the ordinary *homology* that way. When you have a manifold $M$ with first Stiefel-Whitney class $w \in H^1(M;\Bbb Z/2)$, you may define the homology groups with twisted coefficients $H_*(M;\Bbb Z_w)$ using the representation $w: \pi_1(M) \to \pm 1$. Then $H^*_c(M;\Bbb Z) \cong H_{n-*}(M;\Bbb Z_w)$. For instance, in the case of the Mobius band, the latter group is zero, and so compactly supported cohomology is zero.